# Unable to export saved model using simple_save tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use simple_save for tensorflow, but it isn't working :(

Here is my code:

```
def export_model(saved_model_dir, final_tensor_name):
 with tf.Session() as sess:
 with sess.graph.as_default() as graph:
 tf.saved_model.simple_save(
  sess,
  saved_model_dir,
  inputs={'image': tf.placeholder(tf.float32)},
  outputs={'prediction': graph.get_tensor_by_name(final_tensor_name + ":0")}
 )
```

I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value final_training_ops/biases/final_biases
 [[{{node save/SaveV2}}]]
```

I am working with the following tutorial: https://github.com/BartyzalRadek/Multi-label-Inception-net

I've spent so many hours trying to find solutions online and I know it can't be that tough. I already have a graph that is being exported and all I need now is that saved_model.pb. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

NEW UPDATE - CODE BELOW

```
def export_model(saved_model_dir, final_tensor_name):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    with sess.graph.as_default() as graph:
      tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        saved_model_dir,
        inputs={'image': tf.placeholder(tf.string)},
        outputs={'prediction': graph.get_tensor_by_name(final_tensor_name + ":0")}
       )
```

The code runs now, but when I test the saved model, I always get the same result.

IMAGE_LABELING_CODE

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

image_path = sys.argv[1]

image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
               in tf.gfile.GFile("labels.txt")]

with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

Comment: It seems that you need `sess.run(tf.gloabl_variables_initializer())`.

Comment: Thank you! Now the code runs! But when I try to test the saved model, it always returns the same values no matter what input. I have 2 labels and it returns approximately 0.5 per label.

Comment: This may be the problem of model training. You can try to predict the results before they are saved.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: You can use the `sess.run(prediction,feed_dict=['image':...])` prediction to see if the same value is returned before model is saved. If the results are the same value, you need to see if there is a problem with your model structure or code.

Comment: Yes, I get the same result when I use `sess.run(prediction,feed_dict=['image':...])` I'm trying to figure out why is it that this doesn't. When I try to use the graph to make a prediction later, it works. I have added that code in another update above. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As @giser_yugang said maybe you should put at the end of the construction part of the graph: `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` and then at execution, after beginning the session: `sess.run(init)`

Nevertheless, if it were a local variable you would have to add the variable to some collection,  establish the initializer and the run it. For example:

```
a = tf.Variable(..., collections=[tf.GRAPH_KEYS.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
local_init = tf.local_variable_initializer()
...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(local_init)
```

nevertheless, some implementations from tensorflow library go directly to local variables, for example, `tf.metrics` (if they have not changed this) and you just have to define and run `local_init = tf.local_variables_initializer()` and `sess.run(local_init)`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I updated my question above with some new code. I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean since I am very new to TensorFlow, but I feel like I understood it. Anyways, the code I updated above still returns the same values for any image that is passed in as a b64 string. I also have an inception graph creation method and output graph, should I show you that?

Comment: Please, post what is the output that you have and alll the code necessaary to solve the problem. Because, what is the problem exactly? If you want to obtain predictions you should follow @giser_yugang comment on the question

Comment: I have added an update with the code that I use to predict using the trained graph. This code works to generate an accurate prediction. Thanks!!